# Update SQL query to update the custom order for the given posts in the category

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have created a custom table in wordpress db by the name wp_post_reorder and below is the picture which shows how it looks like:-

[Custom order table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZl3w.png)

Now on post publish i am updating the order of the post in the particular category using a meta box

[Meta Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5a6t.png)

on publish_post hook i am calling a function

```
function save_custom_order() {
    if (isset($_POST['post_ID']) && isset($_POST['category_orders'])) {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'post_reorder';
        $post_id = $_POST['post_ID'];
        $category_orders = $_POST['category_orders'];

        foreach ($category_orders as $category_id => $orders) {
            $existing_order = $wpdb->get_var(
                $wpdb->prepare(
                    "SELECT `order` FROM $table_name WHERE post_id = %d AND category_id = %d",
                    $post_id,
                    $category_id
                )
            );

            if ($existing_order !== null) {
                $wpdb->update(
                    $table_name,
                    array('order' => $orders),
                    array('post_id' => $post_id, 'category_id' => $category_id),
                    array('%d'),
                    array('%d', '%d')
                );

                $update_rest = $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name SET `order` = `order` - 1 WHERE category_id = %d AND `order` > %d", $category_id, $orders);
                $wpdb->query($update_rest);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For eg if i am updating the order of post with postid as 366840 from order 1 to 7, now my code is properly updating the value from 1 to 7 but it is not updating the value of the post which are after this post containing the order 2-7.

All i want that after updating the order to 7, the posts from order 2-7 should decrement by 1 i.e it should become 1-6.